# How to install Cloud9 with Node.js 0.6?

Tags: node.js, ide

I'm looking for an offline free ide for node.js.
I was going to use cloud9, but it seems that doesn't work..

I followed this guide https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9

What could I use? Is there any way to use cloud9 with node.js 0.6?

The error of the last version of cloud9 of github: http://pastebin.com/7QEAygfD

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? Clearly it works for someone, but if you won't tell us the problem, there's not much anyone can do to help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: Looks like Cloud9 will have support for node.js v0.6+ any day now: https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/pull/726

Here's what I did to get Cloud9 running on node.js v0.6.9 on Ubuntu

```
git clone git://github.com/gero3/cloud9.git
cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh
(cd cloud9; npm install libxml; npm install formidable)
cloud9/bin/cloud9.sh
```

Looks like there's a couple of missing modules (libxml & formidable) -- it started right up after installing them with `npm`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work! Look at my error. Have you tried by yourself?

Comment: Yep... installed it via the pull request mentioned, with node v0.6.9.

Answer (score 1):

Offline/ Open Source VERSION

You can install the open source version of Cloud9 locally using Sourcemint. The new version will require NodeJS >= 0.6.15.

Please have a look on how to do so, here: https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9

ONLINE VERSION
Select Node Version (0.6.x)

> In Cloud9 IDE you can select a preferred version of node from within the RUN panel on the left of the editor: https://skitch.com/detmarterhuurne/8kykn/select-node-version-cloud9
>
> Or you can select a runtime in the preferences panel also on the left of the editor

Answer (score 0):

cloud9 ide [should have 0.6 support](http://cloud9ide.posterous.com/run-your-projects-on-node-06)

Good alternatives to cloud9 ide include

- [WebStorm 3.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/)
- unix

UPDATE: if you use bin/cloud9.sh will lead the built-in node which is version 0.4. so if you do that even you install node v.6.x you still using node 0.4

Comment: That improvement for cloud9 is only for the online version, isn't it?

Comment: @rodi cloud9 is open source, so the same improvement should apply off line